# Doctrine: update one entity from another

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have `Post` entity. It has [Life Cycle Callbacks](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/events.html#lifecycle-callbacks) with `@ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks` and code:

```
/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist
 * @ORM\PreUpdate
 */
public function updateTimestamps()
{
    $this->post->setUpdatedAt(new DateTime('now'));
}
```

Also I have `Comment` entity. `Comment` has one (or belongs to) `Post`.

I want to update `Post#updatedAt`when `Comment` is updated. How can I do it?

Comment: `$this->getPost()->updateTimestamps()`?

Comment: I won't not work without flush().

Answer (score 1):

On this documentation page, at the very bottom, there are some suggestions made as to how to accommodate something more complex: http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/lifecycle_callbacks.html

In short, these lifecycle events should be for calling internal functionality in your entity, and not for communicating between different entities. For that, you want to use event listeners/subscribers. This other post is very similar to this question and might provide some more guidance: [Doctrine2 Entity PrePersist - Update another entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20141758/doctrine2-entity-prepersist-update-another-entity)

Answer (score 0):

```
/** @ORM\PrePersist @ORM\PreUpdate */
public function updatePostTimeStamp() {
    $this->post->setUpdatedAt(new \DateTime('now'));
    // you should get doctrine entity manager. e.g.
    // $em= MagicSingleton::getDoctrine()
    $em->persist($this->getPost());
}
```

Comment: There is no way to determine EntityManager. The application contains 68 EntityManagers (app/console container:debug | grep ORM.EntityManager | wc -l) and the Entity shouldn't know anything about EM.

Comment: How about Event Listeners?

  http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#listening-and-subscribing-to-lifecycle-events

Answer (score -1):

Your LifecycleCallbacks should be in the Comment entity because you want to trigger it from there. Your callback function should look like this:

```
public function updatePostTimeStamp() {
    $this->getPost()->setUpdatedAt(new \DateTime('now'));
}
```

After a user created or updated a comment you need to do a persist() on the comment and also on the post. Then you can do a flush() and everything will be stored. The persist on the post() is needed to update the post table.

Comment: Why should I use `persist()` for entities, that are already stored in database? Also I need to get `em` to `flush()`.

Comment: Persist is not only for an INSERT statement but also for UPDATE. The Post needs to be updated to update the timestamp of the post. This is not special about Doctrine, with native SQL you would have to do this too. Perhaps updatePostTimeStamp() should be called updatePostLastEventTimeStamp(). Alternatively you could query all Events related to Post and do a MAX(UpdatedAt).